# Unable to receive local IP address of my machine in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the `OS` and `DNS` modules to try and get the local IP address of my computer, but it's failing with the error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND My-MacBook-Pro.local
```

What's weird is that this worked before in a previous project, but not anymore. Here is what I have:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { promises } from 'dns';
import os from 'os';

export const setIPAddress = async (options) => {
  try {
    const { lookup } = promises;
    const { hostname } = os;
    const ipAddress = (await lookup(hostname(), options)).address;

    fs.writeFile(
      './client/network/gateway.js',
      `IP: ${ipAddress}`,
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
      },
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('There was an error encountered when setting IP address', err);
  }
};
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You can get local ip address in this way.

`require('dns').lookup(require('os').hostname(), function (err, add, fam) {
    console.log('Ip address is :  ' + add);
});`

Comment: Sam error, ` address is : Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND My-MacBook-Pro.local`

Comment: Can you reinstall node one time?